# concatenating strings withput space at the begining in python

Tags: python

```
b=''
while True:
    s=input("enter smtg")
    if s== -99:
        break
    b+=s
print(b)
```

I want the output b with proper spaced output between each value of variable s entered. I have tried to join with `b=' '.join([b,s])` and `b=b+' '+s`. The output is spaced properly but with extra space at the begining. I want the statement to be in single line.

For example, if “inputA”, “inputB” and ”inputC” are input; the result should be “inputA inputB inputC”. It should not have extra spaces at the beginning, or the end.

Comment: collect all user input in a list and use `join`, once, at the end. Also please provide an example input with the corresponding, desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
b=''
while True:
    s=input("enter smtg")
    if s== -99:
        break
    b+=s+" "
b=b[:-1]
print(b)
```

or:

```
b=''
while True:
    s=input("enter smtg")
    if s== -99:
        break
    b=b+' '+s
b=b.strip()
print(b)
```

The `strip` function removes any spaces, or tabs from the beginning, or end of a string. It is very helpful in situations like this. However, it is likely that the first example would be more efficient, as you’re telling the program exactly what character to remove, rather than making it check.